# How to retrieve managament groups in hierarchy (managment groups /subscription / resources in each group) using java

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-management

I'm building an application and I need to retrieve all management groups in a hierarchical style like the subscription IDs and that resource informations .

I looked up in the SDK for java :(https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java)

but can't find anything related with my topic

I went through tones of documentations but still didn't find any significant class that can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/managementgroups/management-groups/list?tabs=HTTP) to access the ***management group list*** from azure by using azure REST Api call for the ***list management api***.

To access the above api we should have the following details:

1. Client ID
2. Client Secret
3. Tenant ID

With the help of above credentials, we can generate access token to access the api’s in azure.

*Below is the API to generate the access token.*

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-tenant-id>/oauth2/token`

- *Hit the api using postman:* *

[image]

Use the generated token as header in the below api to access management groups:
https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups?api-version=2020-05-01

[image]

***I have implemented the above scenario using java and spring boot by following the [code](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/Retrieve_Management_groups).***

**Output:**

In my case, I have only one management groups. So, I'm getting one management group as shown below.
[image]

Comment: Thank you your code work just fine but I noticed that you left some sensitive data hard coded so please be careful and change it to placeholder in the java code @Pravallika KV